# java.lang.ClassCastException when reading the json file using java

Tags: java, json, web-services

I want to read a .json file called (results.json) using java and extract the values of the array by the key 'title'.

This is my .json file

```
 [
    {
        "title": {
            "0": "UNIQUE SIGNED HARRY POTTER DELUXE VOLUME SALESMAN DUMMY"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": {
            "0": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone by JK Rowling - Uncorrected Proof/ARC!!"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": {
            "0": "Huge Lego Lot 532 Lbs Pounds Legos Star Wars Castle Harry Potter City Minifigs"
        }
    }
]
```

This is the java code i'm using

```
public class JJ {

public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    readJsonFile();
}

public static void readJsonFile() {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new    FileReader("C:/wamp/www/epsilon/results.json"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Names of the Books:\t" + sCurrentLine);

            Object obj;
            try {

                obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                String name = (String) jsonObject.get("title");

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting an error saying

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Your Json file has an array at the top level. When the JSonParser parses it, it's returning it as a JSONArray. You're trying to cast it to a JSONObject instead (which is like a map, or dictionary.) What you need to do is this:

```
Object obj;
try {

    obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
    for(obj : jsonArray){//not sure of the exact syntax, I don't have an IDE in front of me.
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
        JSONObject realTitle = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("0");
        String name = (String) realTitle.get("title");
    }


} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And in addition, I realize you're reading it line by line. You don't want to do that either. You probably want to read the whole thing first, then parse it.

Comment: jsonObject.get("title") won't return a String, but another JSONObject containing a single key "0".

Comment: Thanks alt for the quick response kyler. I will follow your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/path/to/file/file.txt"));
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObjectRow = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            String name = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("Name");
            String address = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("Address");
            Long telephone = (Long) jsonObjectRow.get("Phone_Number");

        }
```

Comment: Also provide some comment in the answer explaining your code.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue, to solve it just replace this:

```
obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

by:

```
obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject((parser.parse(sCurrentLine)).toString());
```