# Issue while parsing json file

Tags: java, json

Hi I have the code like below .

```
public class offlineAgent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        try {

            String filename = "E://agent.xls";
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("Ubuild_agents");

            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Agent_name");

            rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Agent_status");

            // Sets the authenticator that will be used by the networking code
            // when a proxy or an HTTP server asks for authentication.
            Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator());

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://test:8080/rest2/agents");

            // read text returned by server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url
                    .openStream()));

            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                FileOutputStream fop = null;
                File file;

                file = new File("E:/Test/Results.json");
                fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] contentInBytes = line.getBytes();

                fop.write(contentInBytes);
                fop.flush();
                fop.close();

            }
            in.close();
            String filePath = "E:/Test/Results.json";

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

            System.out.println("The unavailability of Ubuild agents");

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            Object object = jsonParser.parse(reader);
            //JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
            //JSONObject structure = (JSONObject) jsonParser.get("response");
            // Object[] result=(Object[]) structure.get("results");

            //JSONArray lang = (JSONArray) structure.get("results");
            JSONArray lang=new JSONArray();
            lang.add(object);
            System.out.println("Objects"+object);
            System.out.println(lang.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < lang.size(); i++) {

                // System.out.println("The " + i +
                // " element of the array: "+lang.get(i));

            }
            Iterator i = lang.iterator();

            int j = 1;
            while (i.hasNext()) {

                JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();

                System.out.println("i has some data");
                 System.out.println("innerobj" +innerObj);

                if (innerObj.get("status").equals("Offline")) {

                    // System.out.println(innerObj.get("name"));
                    // System.out.println(innerObj.get("status"));
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) j);

                    row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(
                            innerObj.get("name").toString());

                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
                    row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(
                            innerObj.get("status").toString());
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
                    j++;
                }

            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            hwb.write(fileOut);

            fileOut.close();
            // Udeployagent10 crf= new Udeployagent10();

            try {
                if (j != 1) {
                    Access_password_correct1 mail = new Access_password_correct1();
                    mail.mail1();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("all agents are online");
                }
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void mail1() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        String host = "mail.gmail.com";
        String from = "SCM_Team@gmail.com";
        String to = "abcv@gmail.com";
        String fileAttachment = "E://Ubuild_agent.xls";
        Properties props;
        MimeMessage message;
        Session session;
        StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
        String msg1 = "Please find the agent details below";
        String msgBody;
        /*
         * read file
         */
        try {
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    "E://Ubuild_agent.xls"));
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            // int firstRow=sheet.getFirstRowNum();
            // int lastRow=sheet.getLastRowNum();
            msg.append("Hello Team,\n \n");
            msg
                    .append("The unavailability of the agent(s) will impact  that are scheduled to run on the agent.");
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                if (row.getRowNum() > 0) {
                    msg.append("\n");
                    Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cells.hasNext()) {

                        // msg.append(' ');
                        msg.append("\t");
                        msg.append("\n");

                        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                        if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cell.getCellType())
                            msg.append(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cell
                                .getCellType())
                            msg.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN == cell
                                .getCellType())
                            cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    }

                }

            }

            msg.append("\n \n \n Thanks,\n Team");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // msg.append("</body></html>");

        msgBody = msg.toString();

        // Get system properties
        props = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get session
        session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Define message

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        // message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new
        // InternetAddress.parse("abc@gmail.com,abc"));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress
                .parse("test@gmail.com"));

        message
                .setSubject("Alert: One or more  agent(s) detected to be offline");
        // message.setText(msg1);
        // create the message part
        // message.setContent(o, type);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();

        // fill message

        messageBodyPart.setText(msgBody);

        // messageBodyPart.getFileName();
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // multipart.addBodyPart(msg1);
        // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer(fileAttachment);
        System.out.println(st.replace(0, 2, ""));
        String s1 = st.toString();

        messageBodyPart.setFileName(s1);

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send the message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("mail sent successfully");

    }

    public static class CustomAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

        // Called when password authorization is needed
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

            // Get information about the request
            String prompt = getRequestingPrompt();
            String hostname = getRequestingHost();
            InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
            int port = getRequestingPort();
            String username = "admin";
            String password = "admin";



            // Return the information (a data holder that is used by
            // Authenticator)
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());

        }

    }

}
```

Im getting below issue while executing the code .

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
>     at offlineAgent.main(offlineAgent.java:115)

any one have idea about the issue?

Below is the json file

[{"id":21,"name":"SV-HSCBUILD-P2","description":null,"host":null,"status":"Offline","version":"N/A","throughput":1,"activeJobs":0,"maxJobs":5,"ignored":false,"configured":true,"lastOnline":1434135548313,"lastOnlineString":"6/12/15 2:59 PM"},{"id":11,"name":"svl-jbuild-d1-t1","description":"svl-jbuild-d1-t1","host":null,"status":"Online","version":"5.0.0-432508","throughput":1,"activeJobs":0,"maxJobs":5,"ignored":false,"configured":true,"lastOnline":1455402039280,"lastOnlineString":"2/13/16 5:20 PM"},{"id":201,"name":"T1BuildAgent","description":null,"host":null,"status":"Online","version":"6.1.0-637672","throughput":1,"activeJobs":1,"maxJobs":5,"ignored":false,"configured":true,"lastOnline":1455402099897,"lastOnlineString":"2/13/16 5:21 PM"},{"id":65,"name":"Tibco-SVTIBBUILD","description":null,"host":null,"status":"Online","version":"5.0.0-432508","throughput":1,"activeJobs":0,"maxJobs":5,"ignored":false,"configured":true,"lastOnline":1455402542020,"lastOnlineString":"2/13/16 5:29 PM"},{"id":192,"name":"Tibco_t1","description":null,"host":null,"status":"Online","version":"6.1.0-637672","throughput":1,"maxJobs":5,"ignored":false,"configured":false,"lastOnline":1455402561953,"lastOnlineString":"2/13/16 5:29 PM"}]

Comment: Isn't the exception message explanative enough?

Comment: Could you provide the line number code context that is causing the problem? Because the code isn't formatted right, it's hard to know what line/lines are causing the error.

Comment: I guess that you are trying to read it in different manner , instead of using JSONObject you are trying to read it in JSONArray . See how to read and write of java .[Refer](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Comment: `[]` is an array `{}` is an object. Your JSONArray appears not to contain only JSONObject data

Comment: im getting error in below line   JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();

Comment: could please add the json here ?

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133162/java-lang-classcastexception-when-reading-the-json-file-using-java)

Comment: It means what it says.  The error is on line 115, which is apparently the assignment to `innerObj`, based on your comment above.  Study your JSON (which you fail to provide) and figure out if EVERY item at that point is a `JSONArray`, or only some of them.

Comment: Hi GK27 , added  json file.

Answer (score -1):

It's looks like this line (closest to 115 that deals with `Object` casting):

```
JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
```

You need to check if the raw `Object` is an `instanceof` `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`, and parse as necessary. You need to be able to handle both object types.

---

**EDIT**: updating with example code that handles relevant JSON object types.

```
Object o = i.next();
if(o instanceof JSONArray) {
    JSONArray innerObj = (JSONArray) o;
    // handle recursively, perhaps?
    // you need to loop through an array here or pick out the attributes you know you need
} else if(o instanceof JSONObject) {
    JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) o;
    // continue with your usual code
}
```

Comment: What about other data types in json like string, numbers, and boolean? The array could contain those too

Comment: All items in a `JSONArray` will either be a `JSONObject` that you need to get (and cast) the value of, or another `JSONArray`. A JSON tree has no information on the type of data, that's what the parser is meant to decide.

Comment: Umm...  json arrays can contain any valid json string: objects with different key/value pairs, other arrays, numbers, strings, booleans all in the same array

Comment: @prathesh - I've updated with a generic method; I'm not familiar with your application so there isn't much more I can do. @cricket_007 - and in-context to parsing them in Java, a common JSON parsing library that the original poster seems to be using handles all `Object` types as `JSONObject` and all simple lists as a `JSONArray`. I think Maps fall under the `JSONObject` definition.

Comment: If anyone wants to downvote, they can at least explain why, please.